# Bouncing node in Sprite Kit

Tags: iphone, sprite-kit

I move a node by changing its position. And I would like to add a similar to this effect when moving: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiLYjzxyzkI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is with `SKAction`s
This example just move up and down, but combinet with moving up/left/right/down it creates effect that yout character/node is jumping.

You can adjust numbers to look more realistic

`moveDuration` - time it takes for your character/node to move 1 tile

```
runAction(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: character.frame.size.height / 2, duration: moveDuration / 2),  
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -character.frame.size.height / 2, duration: moveDuration / 2),
    ]))
```

if you whant more realistic try this:

```
runAction(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: character.frame.size.height / 2 * 0.5, duration: moveDuration / 6),
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: character.frame.size.height / 2 * 0.35, duration: moveDuration / 6),
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: character.frame.size.height / 2 * 0.15, duration: moveDuration / 6),  
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -character.frame.size.height / 2 * 0.15, duration: moveDuration / 6),
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -character.frame.size.height / 2 * 0.35, duration: moveDuration / 6),
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -character.frame.size.height / 2 * 0.5, duration: moveDuration / 6),
    ]))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!